# Background Color and Image shuffling on Scroll in recyclerView Android using Group Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Below is my `BindableItem` Class which also act as an `adapter` while using Groupie

```
class FilterByAthleteTypeItem(var athleteResponse: AthleteModel, var onFilterAthleteItemClick: OnFilterAthleteItemClick) : BindableItem<FilterItemLayoutBinding>() {

override fun bind(viewBinding: FilterItemLayoutBinding, position: Int) {
    ViewHolder(viewBinding, position)
    viewBinding.executePendingBindings()
    viewBinding.notifyChange()
}

override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.filter_item_layout
}


inner class ViewHolder(var binding: FilterItemLayoutBinding, position: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        athleteResponse.isChecked = binding.playlistSwitch.isChecked
        onFilterAthleteItemClick.onFilterAthleteClicked(athleteResponse)
        notifyChanged()
    }

    init {
        val athleteModel = athleteResponse
        binding.totalItems.text = athleteModel.areelCount.toString()
        binding.playlistSwitch.isChecked = athleteModel.isChecked
        binding.sportName.text = athleteModel.athleteType
        binding.playlistSwitch.setOnClickListener(this)

        when {
            athleteModel.athleteType == "highschool" -> binding.playerLevelImage.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context, R.color.black))
            athleteModel.athleteType == "college" -> binding.playerLevelImage.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context, R.color
                            .college))
            athleteModel.athleteType == "pro" -> binding.playerLevelImage.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context, R.color.pro))
            athleteModel.athleteType == "enthusiast" -> binding.playerLevelImage.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context,
                            R.color.enthusiast))
            athleteModel.athleteType == "military" -> binding.playerLevelImage.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context,
                            R.color.text_color_9b))
            else -> binding.playerLevelImage.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context,
                            R.color.white))
        }

    }

   }
  }

 interface OnFilterAthleteItemClick {
 fun onFilterAthleteClicked(athleteModel: AthleteModel)
 }
```

Here is how I used it in MyActivity

```
    Section section = new Section();
    section.setHeader(headerItemGroupie);
    if (!Utils.isNull(athleteModelList))

        for (int i = 0; i < athleteModelList.size(); i++) {
            AthleteModel athleteModel = athleteModelList.get(i);
            athleteModel.setPosition(i);
            athleteModelList.remove(i);
            athleteModelList.add(i, athleteModel);
            section.add(new FilterByAthleteTypeItem(athleteModelList.get(i), this));
        }
    groupAdapter.add(section);
```

Below is my layout Item file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.areel.android.customview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/totalItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_9b"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:fontPath="@string/font_avenir_heavy"
        app:letterSpacing="0.154"
        tools:text="14,932"/>

    <com.areel.android.customview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/sportName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:fontPath="@string/font_avenir_heavy"
        app:letterSpacing="0.3"
        tools:text="NAME OF SPORT"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.8">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playerLevelImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/playlistSwitch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:button="@drawable/switch_on_off"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my `recyclerView` in `layout`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/filter_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/showFriendLayout"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Now when I scroll the `recyclerView` the background color and Image start shuffling means respective positions of background color doesn't remain appropriate while scrolling
the major problem is the last item has an image as a background, and when I scroll that Image overlaps other backgrounds and shuffle happened
But there is now way to change that image to color so I need more robust solution!!

I am adding the screen shots here
First one, What I have done

[image: What I have done]

And I check items and Scrolls the recyclerview then that last image shuffles its position like below image
The FIfth Image also shuffles on Down side

[image: Issue is]

Comment: Can you post the screencast of what you are trying to achieve and what is currently happening?

Comment: @Droidwala Done

Comment: looks like Viewholder problem somewhere. Will have to replicate code locally to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: Currently I have solved my problem by changing the ImageView to View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the library here.  You have several problems in your posted code.

For starters, you shouldn't be calling `executePendingBindings` or `notifyChange`.  You aren't using the feature of data binding where you bind a model object, so both of those are unnecessary.

Second, the whole point of Groupie (especially with data binding) is that you shouldn't have to create your own ViewHolder.  In fact, yours isn't doing anything.  You can move all the code from your `ViewHolder` class into `FilterByAthleteTypeItem.bind()`.

Last, your problem with images loading in the wrong spots, or duplicated, is a very common issue in RecyclerViews.  You didn't post your image loading code, but I'm guessing it's asynchronously loading images -- meaning they load into a certain view, regardless of whether it's been recycled -- and/or failing to clear the old image from reused viewholders.  I recommend you avoid dealing with this problem entirely by using an image loading library like Picasso or Glide.

Hope that helps!